# undefined method get_uptime for Facter::Util::Uptime:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, puppet, facter

I'm trying to setup a puppet node, but rubygems doesn't seem to behave.

If I run facter on the cli via it's own binary (/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/facter-1.5.8/bin/facter), it works fine, but if I run it through the binary installed by rubygems (/usr/bin/facter), it throws:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/facter/uptime.rb:11: undefined method `get_uptime' for Facter::Util::Uptime:Module (NoMethodError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/facter-1.5.8/lib/facter/util/loader.rb:73:in `load'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/facter-1.5.8/lib/facter/util/loader.rb:73:in `load_file'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/facter-1.5.8/lib/facter/util/loader.rb:38:in `load_all'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/facter-1.5.8/lib/facter/util/loader.rb:33:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/facter-1.5.8/lib/facter/util/loader.rb:33:in `load_all'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/facter-1.5.8/lib/facter/util/loader.rb:30:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/facter-1.5.8/lib/facter/util/loader.rb:30:in `load_all'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/facter-1.5.8/lib/facter/util/collection.rb:90:in `load_all'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/facter-1.5.8/lib/facter.rb:95:in `to_hash'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/facter-1.5.8/bin/facter:137
        from /usr/bin/facter:19:in `load'
        from /usr/bin/facter:19
```

I've tried removing rubygems and reinstalling as well as reinstalling the gem, but nothing seems to work.

I'm assuming something is cached somewhere, because it throws the same error when I'm trying to run puppet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you may have installed `facter` outside of rubygems before installing it with rubygems.

You'll notice the final file in the stacktrace is `/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/facter/uptime.rb` instead of being a file in `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/facter-1.5.8`.

You should check if the files in `/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/facter` are indeed just an older version of factor and if so, you should be able to delete them or move them to a differently named directory and it will fix your problems.

Comment: brilliant, thanks! it was installed via apt-get. Removed it and removed the gem, reinstalled and it works fine now.